# Getting ITMS-4238 “Redundant Binary Upload” error, I have changed everything

Tags: xamarin.ios

My app has been rejected a couple of times because of my code errors I made in the application.

The first build was (1.0) the second build was (1.0.1) And the third build was (1.0.2).

I want to do a fourth build because I have changed all my code and finalised everything. I was ready to upload so I changed the build number to (1.0.4), but it came with the error Redundant Binary Upload. So I changed it to (1.0.5) And (1.0.6) And (1.0.7) And (1.0.8) And (2.0) and (2.1) and (2.0.1.1).

After changing the build number about 8 times it still came up with the error Redundant Binary Upload.

I am using Xamarin and there are 2 things you could change the version number and the Build number. Am I doing something wrong? I have watched a lot of tutorials and it came up with increasing but it just didn't work this time. Previously it did work (exactly three times but after the fourth upload it stopped working). How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a similar issue until I found out my `Info.plist`'s `CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString` keys values needed to be manually updated.